# Case insensitive header params for API request

Tags: htaccess, rest-api, server

I am making API requests with token based Auth mechanism. Here is example request.

```
TokenRequest({
     method: 'POST',
     url: {URL HERE},
     headers: {'Authorization': Bearer {token}},
     params: {
        ... params ...
     }
}).then...Handle the rest
```

The problem is with header param **`Authorization`** as per standards it should be case insensitive and almost all JS clients (`Fetch, Axios`) are converting headers to lowercase therefore it becomes `authorization` and server expects `Authorization` (with capital A).

My question is how to make all header params case insensitive? so it can accept params in any case.

Comment: "...how to make all header params case insensitive?" - Don't you mean "case _sensitive_" - since that is what your "server" (although I think you mean "script") is expecting? (HTTP request headers are already case insensitive with regards to the "server". eg. Apache)

Comment: Server is case sensitive right now and i want to make it insensitive. I am sending params in lowercase but server needs first letter capital.

Comment: Is this a WordPress question? WordPress does not support bearer tokens in the REST API, or otherwise, are you trying to use a plugin? Or is this something else?

Comment: I am using WP.. Auth token is just an example. I wanted to know is there a way to make HTTP headers case insensitive in WP, probably using htaccess, wp-config or something.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be a "fault" of the way WordPress (the "server") is reading the HTTP request headers. (If they are being read into an associative array without any normalisation then the comparison will naturally be case-sensitive.) This should arguably be "fixed" in WP.

However, it's possible to create a "workaround" in `.htaccess` and re-create the HTTP request header with the required case. ie. `Authorization` (with capital A) instead of `authorization` (all lowercase, or whatever case is passed). However, you would need to do this for each header as required.

For example:

```
# 1. Save the current value in env var (Case of header name does not matter)
SetEnvIf authorization (.*) HEADER_VALUE=$1

# 2. Delete the current header (Case of header name does not matter)
RequestHeader unset "authorization" env=HEADER_VALUE

# 3. Recreate header with the required case (Case of header name is preserved)
#    env=HEADER_VALUE ensures the header is only set if it was set to begin with
RequestHeader set "Authorization" %{AUTHORIZATION_VALUE}e env=HEADER_VALUE
```

Any comparison that Apache performs on the headers is case-insensitive, so unset'ing `Authorization` or `AUTHORIZATION` will do the same thing. As will reading the value of `Authorization` or `AUTHORIZATION`.

You do have to completely `unset` the header before `set`'ing that header again in order to preserve the case of the required header name. `edit`'ing the request header does not edit the name, only the value.

IMO it's a bit "unusual" for these JS libraries to send all lowercase headers when HTTP header *convention* is to use camel-case, and let the servers canonicalise the request as necessary.

Comment: Note that the HTTP spec says header values are case insensitive. A standard conforming webserver should not behave differently depending on the case of the headers. This is why most new JS http libraries are using all lowercase headers, as it makes the internal code simpler (and http 2 only has forced lowercase headers)